# How to update an existing object using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js

So I'm trying to make a command (`/performance add`) that adds points to the target user.
Basically if the command is `/performance add Someone#0000 5` then it'll get the targeted user's points and add 5 to them.

So,
Before command:

```
User: Someone#0000
Points: 0
```

After command:

```
User: Someone#0000
Points: 5
```

Code:

```
const db = require('../../Models/PointsDB');
db.findOne({ GuildID: interaction.guildId, UserID: Target.id }, async (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!data) {
        data = new db({
            GuildID: interaction.guildId,
            UserID: Target.id,
            Points: PointsGiven
        });
    } else {
        // That's where I'm struggling
    }
    data.save()
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Up (I need help)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the data then add on the number provided.

Example:

```js
const db = require('../../Models/PointsDB');
db.findOne({ GuildID: interaction.guildId, UserID: Target.id }, async (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!data) {
        data = new db({
            GuildID: interaction.guildId,
            UserID: Target.id,
            Points: PointsGiven
        });
    } else {
        // Find the current amount of points then add on the provided amount of points
        // The parseInt function converts a string to an integer value
        data.Points = parseInt(data.Points) + parseInt(PointsGiven)
    }
    data.save()
});
```